# Views show through an absolutely positioned View. The View underneath can intercept touches

Tags: reactjs, react-native, touch-event

I am trying to code a dropdown menu. It looks like this so far (this is not a complete implementation yet).

```
   export default function DropDownMenu({ multiSelect, items = [] }) {
   const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(items[0])
   const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

   return (
      <View>
         <View
            style={{
               backgroundColor: 'transparent',
               borderColor: colors.colorOffWhite,
               borderWidth: 2,
               borderRadius: 5,
            }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
               style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  justifyContent: 'space-between',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  paddingHorizontal: 10,
                  paddingVertical: 5,
                  flex: 1,
               }}
               onPress={() => {
                  setOpen(true)
               }}>
               {items.length > 0 ? (
                  <Text
                     style={{
                        color: colors.colorOffWhite,
                        fontSize: 16,
                     }}>
                     {selectedItem?.label}
                  </Text>
               ) : (
                  <Text
                     style={{
                        color: colors.colorOffWhite,
                        fontSize: 16,
                     }}>
                     Hello zero
                  </Text>
               )}

               <Ionicons
                  name={open ? 'chevron-down' : 'chevron-up'}
                  size={24}
                  color={colors.colorOffWhite}
                  style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
               />
            </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>

         {open ? (
            <View style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 200,
                    backgroundColor: colors.colorOffWhite,
                    position: 'absolute',
                    borderRadius: 5,
                }}>
                    {items.length > 0 ? 
                        items.map(item => <Text key={item.label}>{item.label}</Text>) : null
                    }
                </View>
         ) : null}
      </View>
   )
}
```

The problem is this: when I press the dropdown container I present the absolutely positioned menu. It looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the TextInput field underneath the **absolutely** positioned menu is still able to intercept the touches even though the menu is on top. Does this have to do with the fact that my menu is absolutely positioned or is it something else. How to I get the results I'm looking for. I added a blue background in one of the photos. You can see that everything behind the view shows through. I don't know if it's relevant but this form is inside a keyboard-aware-scroll-view.

Please help me not to hate React Native......( weird shit like this happens all the time with this framework  )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is in fact due to absolutely positioned dropdown menu. Positioning only detaches it from normal view and places it relative to parent. I guess you are trying to achieve dropdown menu to be on top when it is opened. You should use zIndex for defining zStack. But much better solution would be to use Modal as you want anything to be on top and anything other than that to be non touchable.

1. You can get the position of dropdown and open modal when "open is true" and show the dropdown menu in that position inside a modal.
2. All the other things will be below modal so non touchable.
3. On top of that you can touch outside the dropdown menu to close the dropdown as well. Great UX

Comment: I may try that.....I don't know. I used Zindex to get it working on iOS......but then Android doesn't work. They joys of working in React Native I guess

Comment: Sometime in Android setting elevation: anyNumber; resolves the zIndex property not working, Weird but this happens to me bunch of times.